# BeautifulSoup shuffles the attributes of html tags

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have an issue with BeautifukSoup. Whenever I parse an HTML input, it changes the order of the attributes (e.g. class, id) of the HTML tags.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tags = BeautifulSoup('<span id="100" class="test"></span>', "html.parser")
print(str(tags))
```

Prints:

```
<span class="test" id="100"></span>
```

As you can see, the `class` and `id` order was changed. How can I prevent such behavior?

I am unfamiliar with web development, but I know that the order of the attributes doesn't matter.

My main goal here is to preserve the original shape of the HTML input after parsing it because I want to loop through the tags and match them (at character-level) with other HTML texts.

Comment: When it parses it, it doesn't preserve the order, since it's not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, the order of attributes in HTML doesn't matter. But if you really want unsorted attributes, you can do:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter


class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        yield from tag.attrs.items()


tags = BeautifulSoup('<span id="100" class="test"></span>', "html.parser")

print(tags.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()).decode())
```

Prints:

```html
<span id="100" class="test"></span>
```

---

EDIT: To not close void tags you can try:

```py
class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            void_element_close_prefix=""
        )  # <-- use void_element_close_prefix="" here

    def attributes(self, tag):
        yield from tag.attrs.items()


tags = BeautifulSoup(
    """<input id="NOT_CLOSED_TAG" type="Button">""",
    "html.parser",
)

print(tags.encode(formatter=UnsortedAttributes()).decode())
```

Prints:

```html
<input id="NOT_CLOSED_TAG" type="Button">
```

Comment: I have something similar which is, if a tag is not closed, beautifulsoup closes it (e.g. `<input>` becomes `<input/>`). Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: @Minions That's harder problem, because each parser (`html.parser`, `html5lib`, `lxml`) handles this little bit different. I've edited my answer, you can try put `void_element_close_prefix=""` to the constructor in formatter.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort @Andrej!

It works actually, but only for the `input` tag. If I use something like this `<span id="100" class="test">`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Minions I can only point you how `bs4` handles special HTML tags (after all, it's HTML/XML parser): https://git.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/tree/bs4/builder/__init__.py?h=4.13#n454 You can subclass `TreeBuilder` and use custom `empty_element_tags`, but this is more work...